# Loading Desired Policy Implementation in JVM (Loading the value of policy.provider in Java security properties file)

Tags: java, security, policy, javapolicy

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Policy.html), the default Policy implementation can be changed by setting the value of the "policy.provider" security property (in the Java security properties file) to the fully qualified name of the desired Policy subclass implementation.

I created my own implementation of the policy provider class and did the changes accordingly to the Java security properties file. But the class didn't get loaded . After bit researching I came across this [whitepaper](http://www.tedneward.com/files/Papers/JavaPolicy/JavaPolicy.pdf),which says simply "create a "classes" directory under the "jre" directory and place the Policy implementation there. Now the bootstrap ClassLoader will pick up the MyPolicy implementation". Though I tried that still it ws a failure.

How can I make my policy implementation available to the bootstrap ClassLoader for the successful loading?

Comment: just wondering ..why u wanna do so?

Comment: Coz I'm working in a  multi-tenant scenario,hence i need to specify attributes to threads that are running, according to some criteria
Therefore I need my own Policy Implementation :)